# Twtitter Bootstrap modal shown event firing multible times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap

I am assigning a click event to a button in a modal when the event shown has been fire:

```
modal.on('shown', function(){
    modal.on('click', '.modal-confirm', function(e){
        ...
    });
});
```

My problem is that i have tabs in my modal, and when switching tabs the modal.shown event gets fired every time i click a tab, and thereby assiges another click event to the button each time. How do i prevent this from happening? Ofc. i can add an boolean to check if the events has been assigned, but it would be nice if i didnt have to :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use new version of bootstrap that has two events `shown.bs.tab` and `shown.bs.modal` or use following code to prevent several bindings

```
modal.off('shown').on('shown', function(){
    modal.off('click').on('click', '.modal-confirm', function(e){
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually used the event `shown.bs.modal` to start with and it still fired multible times, kinda wired.. cant see the use of it if it fires on tab switching as the example also dose. 
Nice way to unassign events, think i am gonna use this untill a fix for the events is available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's good practice, but you can attach a variable to the modal-confirm element saying that you've assigned the click() event for it already:

```
modal.on('shown', function(){
    if ($(this).find('.modal-confirm').data('hasEvent') != null) {
        modal.on('click', '.modal-confirm', function(e){
            ...
        });
    }
});
```